# \n as3 pasting to Clipboard

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to send a large text string to the clipboard for pasting into a different application. Within the string are some new line tags \n. If I send the string to a dynamic text field in flash it works just fine, but if I copy the string to the clipboard and from there paste into a notepad, the line breaks dont work.

Any suggestions?

Example:

```
var output:String;
output = "This is the first line" + "\n" + "This is the second line";
System.setClipboard(output);
```

Thanks

Comment: depends on the OS you're pasting the code. If it's windows, try \r\n instead of \n
See this on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: Ok new issue. On the app I'm creating, I need the user to input text first, text that has numerous lines. Although \r\n works for the new lines I add, the lines I dont do anything with from the input aren't outputing correctly, they all end up on the one line when pasted back to notepad. (windows)

Comment: paste it into something like notepad++..regular ole notepad is garbage

Comment: Not an option, its for an organization that only have regular notepad:(

Comment: added answer below for replacing linebreaks

Comment: paste into wordpad (comes with windows), save as txt, open in notepad and viola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace them with a regular expression:

```
var reg:RegExp = new RegExp("\n", "gi");
newString = inputString.replace(reg, "\r\n");
```

Comment: Tried exactly what you have, and also tried variations but still outputs as one continuous line. 
`var reg:RegExp = new RegExp("\n", "gi"); topQuarter2 = topQuarter.replace(reg, "\r\n");`

Comment: could be flash uses \r as line breaks. try changing the regexp to \r instead of \n